# Column with auto_increment default value is NULL when querying

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the a column in my table called `spon_applicant_ID`, it looks like this:

[image]

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` default value is working just fine:

[image]

But when I try to pull the value from the database, it is `NULL`:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', 'user', 'PW');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM spon_applicants sa LEFT OUTER JOIN spon_results sr ON sa.spon_applicant_ID = sr.spon_applicant_ID WHERE sr.spon_results_ID IS NULL ';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

var_dump($results);
```

My results look like:

```
array(17) {
  [0]=>
  array(37) {
    ["spon_applicant_ID"]=>
    NULL
    ["application_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-02-04 16:41:16"
```

And so on.

How can I use reference the `spon_applicant_ID` field from the database? Is my understanding of `AUTO_INCREMENT` correct, as it is the mySQL equivalent as an identity?

Comment: Should be SELECT sa.spon_applicant_ID FROM .... Becuase of same column name in both tables

Comment: @devpro, could you make this an answer? This was correct. Thank you.

Comment: alright, i will thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From your last comments:**

> *@devpro, could you make this an answer? This was correct. Thank you. – etm124 1 hour ago*

You need to use alias along with column name because your column names are same in both tables.

**Example:**

```
SELECT sa.spon_applicant_ID ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use only `LEFT JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER` give null when doesn't have the equivalent value